# XSL FO Reading first fo:table node just after a concrete comment

Tags: c#, xml, xsl-fo, xmldocument, xmlreader

I have a big XSL FO file.

In this file I have multiple fo:table objects nested and all them are not identified through a unique id attribute to allow search each one by its unique Id.
Each fo:table, has a comment just at the beginning which contains and unique Id, but this Id is not always the same, it is different each time, even for the same table. Anyway I know how to search for this comment by analyzing the file structure that is always the same.

Now I have the comment object that I want but now I am facing with the following problem: I need to get the first object immediatelly following this comment, in this case, first fo:table object. So how can I do this?

```
<!--  begin table FOPTable { id: 1005 cur_size: 0.0 prv_size: 3.25    prev: 1004 cols: 1 locks: 3 flow:null }    --> 

<fo:table font-size="8pt" font-family="sans-serif" table-layout="fixed">   <fo:table-column column-width="14.35cm" /> 
<fo:table-body>
  <fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-right="2.0pt" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="8pt">   <fo:block    text-align="end">LINE 1</fo:block>    
    </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell padding-top="2.0pt" padding-right="2.0pt" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="8pt">
      <fo:block text-align="end">LINE 2</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>      
   </fo:table-row>   
</fo:table-body>   
</fo:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the template for the comment, to select the `fo:table`:

```
following-sibling::*[1]
```

To select the `fo:table`

```
fo:table[preceding-sibling::comment()[1][contains(., 'id: 1005')]
```

(Note that that would only work from the parent node of the `fo:table`.  What an XPath selects depends also on the context where you are evaluating the XPath (unless the XPath starts with `/` or `//`, that is).)

Comment: I think the user is looking for a c#,  xmlreader solution not xpath/xsl. Maybe use selectsinglenode and tony,s xpath.